# Auto height with Titled panes

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I was tinkering with Scene builder to get UI designed as good as possible, but I have problem with positioning titled panes in Javafx. 
As you may see I have Grid pane with titled panes inside anchor pane with top, left and right anchors set and textarea with bottom, left and right anchors set.

What I want:
Grid pane with titled panes should be at top and when all titled panes are collapsed grid should just have height of that label of pane. The rest of space should be occupied by text area.

How can I achieve this?

[image: main window]
(there's text area above)

[image: structure]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.162-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <GridPane>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Memory" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Registers" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Stack" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <TextArea editable="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <ToolBar>
        <items>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="End" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Step forward" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**EDIT:**
I used @Sedric 's code, with small change of removing wrapper for a grid (was it really necessary?). Changing  pref height of that grid prevents it from collapsing:
[image: main]
(red background on grid to red for greater visibility)

I tried setting row, grid and every titled pane with pref h = 200 and min h = 0. Also changed vgrow to never, also doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.162-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ToolBar>
         <items>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="End" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Step forward" />
         </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <GridPane>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>  
         <children>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Memory" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Registers" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Stack" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <TextArea editable="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It seems that if you set the `GridPane's`` preferredHeight` after clicking on the left or right tab of the `GridPane`, this causes your problem. If you set it to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE`, it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be best to use a `VBox` as the root in this case. Then the `TextArea` to `VGrow = "Always"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ToolBar>
         <items>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="End" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Step forward" />
         </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <GridPane>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="0.0" valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <GridPane>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Memory" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Registers" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Stack" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ListView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <TextArea editable="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I change default height of a grid to keep collapsing working? If I change any preffered height of a grid / titled pane it stops collapsing, just leaves blank space.

Comment: Use my code or click on the grid's left or right tab and set min height to zero.

Comment: Let me know if  `set min-height to zero` helped.

Comment: I used your code, but setting pref height prevents it from collapsing even with min h = 0. https://imgur.com/a/eNUCb

Comment: I think something is with pref values and hbox, I'll do some research.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163445/discussion-between-sedrick-and-jump3r).

Comment: I don't know if I understand your new problem